# Preserve react component state on unmount

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

React newbie here: I have noticed that the component state gets cleared on unmount. is there a way to prevent it? is it using redux?

Comment: Yes you can use a state management tool like Redux. Or you can use browser's local storage.

Answer (score 1):

As you say, when a component is unmount you can not access to the state. And thats the way it is because the lifecicle of the component.

What you can do is try to **save the state of the component that was instantiated while it is mounted and every time it is updated.**

- You can use the storage and use simple javascript.
- You can have the state in the parent or another ancester instance.
- **You can have the state in the redux store**. Note that your component will receive the vars as props, so it wont be the state properly said.

  You can use [redux](https://redux.js.org/introduction/getting-started) in order to manage the state and the states values through time. I recommend you the [redux-devtools-extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/redux-devtools/lmhkpmbekcpmknklioeibfkpmmfibljd?hl=en) and also this [article](https://medium.com/the-web-tub/time-travel-in-react-redux-apps-using-the-redux-devtools-5e94eba5e7c0) about it.

Answer (score 1):

You have a plethora of options. You can either use a state management tool, like [redux](https://redux.js.org/), [context API](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) and so on, or you can pass-in a callback to your parent component and trigger it on [`childComponentWillUnmount`](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#adding-lifecycle-methods-to-a-class) like this:

ParentComponent.jsx:

```
childComponentWillUnmount = (data) => {
 console.log('my data', data);
}

render(){
  return <div>
    <Child componentUnmountCallback={this.childComponentWillUnmount()}/>
  <div>
}
<div>
```

Child.jsx

```
...

componentWillUnmount() {
   this.props.childComponentWillUnmount(this.state);

}

...
```